# Nouns modified by adverbs?

Tags: nouns, adverbs, semantics

I am curious to find out information about the semantics of ungrammatical phrases like "Suddenly Susan" (a film title) or "Purely Pickles" (a food brand), where an adverb modifies a noun. Any information would be helpful. Thank you!

Comment: Titles and names don't have to follow the same rules as normal sentences.

Answer (score 2):

**Titles and headlines** are rarely sentences and have their own grammar formed by traditional usage and the need to attract paying customers/buyers.

They *usually* have some connection with the item, article, book, song, etc. Their construction is often characterised by omissions. These omissions arise because of the lack of space - titles and headlines are usually printed in large letters on a page or label - and they need to be able to be read “at a glance” and be memorable.

"**Suddenly Susan**" seems to be a shortening of "*[Everything was normal and then]* suddenly, *[there was]* Susan!” where “[there was] Susan” = Susan suddenly appeared and changed everything.

**"Purely Pickles"** is a name that was chosen by someone, and the rule with names is **there are no rules whatsoever**. In this case, however, the root word “pure” has several nuances (i) entirely; only; nothing more than (ii) utterly (iii) unadulterated; (iv) clean; wholesome.  Thus **Purely Pickles** says to the reader, “This jar contains only fresh healthy pickles and no additives or unwanted ingredients whatsoever.”

**Purely modifies “contains” adverbially.**

Compare

“A: You said that English was easy to learn…”

B: “Yes, but I said that purely because (= for no other reason than) you were about to give up.”

You Can thus understand “Purely Pickles” as “This contains nothing but pickles.” Or “We (i.e. the company) make **only unadulterated** pickles and nothing else.”

Comment: Thank you, that is very helpful. My takeaway here is that these adverb-noun combinations assume that a cognitive process by the reader will add the missing pieces and create the more complete semantics. Did I get it right?